# How to remove the indent after enumerate

Tags: lists, indentation

I have made a list using enumerate. Here's the code.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}


% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%Custom Styles Defined Here % %
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}


% %Document Starts Here % %
\begin{document}
%
% paper title
% can use linebreaks \\ within to get better formatting as desired
\title{AAAAAAA AAAAAAA  AAAAAA}
%
%
% author names and IEEE memberships
% note positions of commas and nonbreaking spaces ( ~ ) LaTeX will not break
% a structure at a ~ so this keeps an author's name from being broken across
% two lines.
% use \thanks{} to gain access to the first footnote area
% a separate \thanks must be used for each paragraph as LaTeX2e's \thanks
% was not built to handle multiple paragraphs
%

\author{XXX~XXX, %~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
        YYY~YYY, %~\IEEEmembership{Fellow,~OSA,}
        ZZZ~ZZZ and~AAA~AAA %~\IEEEmembership{Life~Fellow,~IEEE}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{M. Shell is with the Department
of Electrical and Computer Engineering, Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta,
GA, 30332 USA e-mail: (see http://www.michaelshell.org/contact.html).}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{J. Doe and J. Doe are with Anonymous University.}% <-this % stops a space
\thanks{Manuscript received April 19, 2005; revised January 11, 2007.}}

% note the % following the last \IEEEmembership and also \thanks - 
% these prevent an unwanted space from occurring between the last author name
% and the end of the author line. i.e., if you had this:
% 
% \author{....lastname \thanks{...} \thanks{...} }
%                     ^------------^------------^----Do not want these spaces!
%
% a space would be appended to the last name and could cause every name on that
% line to be shifted left slightly. This is one of those "LaTeX things". For
% instance, "\textbf{A} \textbf{B}" will typeset as "A B" not "AB". To get
% "AB" then you have to do: "\textbf{A}\textbf{B}"
% \thanks is no different in this regard, so shield the last } of each \thanks
% that ends a line with a % and do not let a space in before the next \thanks.
% Spaces after \IEEEmembership other than the last one are OK (and needed) as
% you are supposed to have spaces between the names. For what it is worth,
% this is a minor point as most people would not even notice if the said evil
% space somehow managed to creep in.



% The paper headers
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~6, No.~1, January~2007}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for Journals}
% The only time the second header will appear is for the odd numbered pages
% after the title page when using the twoside option.





% make the title area
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
%\boldmath
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{abstract}
% IEEEtran.cls defaults to using nonbold math in the Abstract.
% This preserves the distinction between vectors and scalars. However,
% if the journal you are submitting to favors bold math in the abstract,
% then you can use LaTeX's standard command \boldmath at the very start
% of the abstract to achieve this. Many IEEE journals frown on math
% in the abstract anyway.

% Note that keywords are not normally used for peerreview papers.
\begin{IEEEkeywords}
Charge Pump, Energy Harvesting, CNFET, DC/DC Converter.
\end{IEEEkeywords}






% For peer review papers, you can put extra information on the cover
% page as needed:
% \ifCLASSOPTIONpeerreview
% \begin{center} \bfseries EDICS Category: 3-BBND \end{center}
% \fi
%
% For peerreview papers, this IEEEtran command inserts a page break and
% creates the second title. It will be ignored for other modes.
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle



\section{Introduction}
% The very first letter is a 2 line initial drop letter followed
% by the rest of the first word in caps.
% 
% form to use if the first word consists of a single letter:
% \IEEEPARstart{A}{demo} file is ....
% 
% form to use if you need the single drop letter followed by
% normal text (unknown if ever used by IEEE):
% \IEEEPARstart{A}{}demo file is ....
% 
% Some journals put the first two words in caps:
% \IEEEPARstart{T}{his demo} file is ....
% 
% Here we have the typical use of a "T" for an initial drop letter
% and "HIS" in caps to complete the first word.
\IEEEPARstart{T}{he} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla fa.
  \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl.
\end{enumerate}%
%
The rest of the paper is organized as follows. Section II provides an introduction to Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.

\section{Carbon Nanotube Field Effect Transistors}
\indent
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.

% needed in second column of first page if using \IEEEpubid
%\IEEEpubidadjcol

\subsubsection{Subsubsection Heading Here}
Subsubsection text here.


% An example of a floating figure using the graphicx package.
% Note that \label must occur AFTER (or within) \caption.
% For figures, \caption should occur after the \includegraphics.
% Note that IEEEtran v1.7 and later has special internal code that
% is designed to preserve the operation of \label within \caption
% even when the captionsoff option is in effect. However, because
% of issues like this, it may be the safest practice to put all your
% \label just after \caption rather than within \caption{}.
%
% Reminder: the "draftcls" or "draftclsnofoot", not "draft", class
% option should be used if it is desired that the figures are to be
% displayed while in draft mode.
%
%\begin{figure}[!t]
%\centering
%\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{myfigure}
% where an .eps filename suffix will be assumed under latex, 
% and a .pdf suffix will be assumed for pdflatex; or what has been declared
% via \DeclareGraphicsExtensions.
%\caption{Simulation Results}
%\label{fig_sim}
%\end{figure}

% Note that IEEE typically puts floats only at the top, even when this
% results in a large percentage of a column being occupied by floats.


% An example of a double column floating figure using two subfigures.
% (The subfig.sty package must be loaded for this to work.)
% The subfigure \label commands are set within each subfloat command, the
% \label for the overall figure must come after \caption.
% \hfil must be used as a separator to get equal spacing.
% The subfigure.sty package works much the same way, except \subfigure is
% used instead of \subfloat.
%
%\begin{figure*}[!t]
%\centerline{\subfloat[Case I]\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{subfigcase1}%
%\label{fig_first_case}}
%\hfil
%\subfloat[Case II]{\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{subfigcase2}%
%\label{fig_second_case}}}
%\caption{Simulation results}
%\label{fig_sim}
%\end{figure*}
%
% Note that often IEEE papers with subfigures do not employ subfigure
% captions (using the optional argument to \subfloat), but instead will
% reference/describe all of them (a), (b), etc., within the main caption.


% An example of a floating table. Note that, for IEEE style tables, the 
% \caption command should come BEFORE the table. Table text will default to
% \footnotesize as IEEE normally uses this smaller font for tables.
% The \label must come after \caption as always.
%
%\begin{table}[!t]
%% increase table row spacing, adjust to taste
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
% if using array.sty, it might be a good idea to tweak the value of
% \extrarowheight as needed to properly center the text within the cells
%\caption{An Example of a Table}
%\label{table_example}
%\centering
%% Some packages, such as MDW tools, offer better commands for making tables
%% than the plain LaTeX2e tabular which is used here.
%\begin{tabular}{|c||c|}
%\hline
%One & Two\\
%\hline
%Three & Four\\
%\hline
%\end{tabular}
%\end{table}


% Note that IEEE does not put floats in the very first column - or typically
% anywhere on the first page for that matter. Also, in-text middle ("here")
% positioning is not used. Most IEEE journals use top floats exclusively.
% Note that, LaTeX2e, unlike IEEE journals, places footnotes above bottom
% floats. This can be corrected via the \fnbelowfloat command of the
% stfloats package.



\section{Conclusion}
The conclusion goes here.





% if have a single appendix:
%\appendix[Proof of the Zonklar Equations]
% or
%\appendix  % for no appendix heading
% do not use \section anymore after \appendix, only \section*
% is possibly needed

% use appendices with more than one appendix
% then use \section to start each appendix
% you must declare a \section before using any
% \subsection or using \label (\appendices by itself
% starts a section numbered zero.)
%


\appendices
\section{Proof of the First Zonklar Equation}
Appendix one text goes here.

% you can choose not to have a title for an appendix
% if you want by leaving the argument blank
\section{}
Appendix two text goes here.


% use section* for acknowledgement
\section*{Acknowledgment}


The authors would like to thank...


% Can use something like this to put references on a page
% by themselves when using endfloat and the captionsoff option.
\ifCLASSOPTIONcaptionsoff
  \newpage
\fi



% trigger a \newpage just before the given reference
% number - used to balance the columns on the last page
% adjust value as needed - may need to be readjusted if
% the document is modified later
%\IEEEtriggeratref{8}
% The "triggered" command can be changed if desired:
%\IEEEtriggercmd{\enlargethispage{-5in}}

% references section

% can use a bibliography generated by BibTeX as a .bbl file
% BibTeX documentation can be easily obtained at:
% http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/doc/
% The IEEEtran BibTeX style support page is at:
% http://www.michaelshell.org/tex/ieeetran/bibtex/
%\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
% argument is your BibTeX string definitions and bibliography database(s)
%\bibliography{IEEEabrv,../bib/paper}
%
% <OR> manually copy in the resultant .bbl file
% set second argument of \begin to the number of references
% (used to reserve space for the reference number labels box)
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{IEEEhowto:kopka}
H.~Kopka and P.~W. Daly, \emph{A Guide to \LaTeX}, 3rd~ed.\hskip 1em plus
  0.5em minus 0.4em\relax Harlow, England: Addison-Wesley, 1999.

\end{thebibliography}

% biography section
% 
% If you have an EPS/PDF photo (graphicx package needed) extra braces are
% needed around the contents of the optional argument to biography to prevent
% the LaTeX parser from getting confused when it sees the complicated
% \includegraphics command within an optional argument. (You could create
% your own custom macro containing the \includegraphics command to make things
% simpler here.)
%\begin{biography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{mshell}}]{Michael Shell}
% or if you just want to reserve a space for a photo:

\begin{IEEEbiography}{Michael Shell}
Biography text here.
\end{IEEEbiography}

% if you will not have a photo at all:
\begin{IEEEbiographynophoto}{John Doe}
Biography text here.
\end{IEEEbiographynophoto}

% insert where needed to balance the two columns on the last page with
% biographies
%\newpage

\begin{IEEEbiographynophoto}{Jane Doe}
Biography text here.
\end{IEEEbiographynophoto}

% You can push biographies down or up by placing
% a \vfill before or after them. The appropriate
% use of \vfill depends on what kind of text is
% on the last page and whether or not the columns
% are being equalized.

%\vfill

% Can be used to pull up biographies so that the bottom of the last one
% is flush with the other column.
%\enlargethispage{-5in}



% that's all folks
\end{document}
```

The problem is that when I make a preview of this, I get indentation(for two lines) in the paragraph just after the list. I don't want that. How can I remove that? I am new to LaTeX. Please help. Here's the screenshot of generated pdf.
[image: Generated PDF]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Have you tried to use `\noindent` ?

Comment: Yes. I did. In addition I also tried putting the % after \end{enumerate}, so that the blank space don't count. No use.

Comment: @AdityaTyagi: Without a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) it's hard to tell what's causing the problem. What packages have you loaded? When I compile your code, adding `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}...\end{document}`, I don't have the problem you showed.

Comment: I am sorry I did not know about MWEs. I just downloaded the tempelate of IEEE journal from here. https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/ieee-journal/  Here is the starting of the code.
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%Custom Styles Defined Here % %
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
% %Document Starts Here % %
\begin{document}

Comment: Please edit your question and add the preamble you mention in your comment.

Comment: You have edited the question but not enough: please make a document so that people can reproduce the problem. fragments are not that helpful.

Comment: If you try compiling the codes provided, your problem is still not reproducible.

Comment: I have edited the question and pasted the entire code. Please forgive me for such lame attempts, but I really can't figure a way out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The culprit is the `\IEEEPARstart`.  Despite what the style file says this has not been fixed to allow direct inclusion of environments in the initial paragraph.  To work around this you can just make sure there is a `\par` before your enumerate.  Here is the same text first time without `\par`, second time with:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{he} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
ea commodo consequat. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc
putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per
seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc
nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum:
\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
  diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
  erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci
  tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
  velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla fa.
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
  diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
  erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci
  tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl.
\end{enumerate}
The rest of the paper is organized as follows. Section II provides an
introduction to Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in
vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.

\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{T}{he} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
ea commodo consequat. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc
putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per
seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc
nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum:\par
\begin{enumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
  diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
  erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci
  tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
  velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla fa.
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
  diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
  erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci
  tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl.
\end{enumerate}
The rest of the paper is organized as follows. Section II provides an
introduction to Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea
commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in
vulputate velit esse molestie consequat.

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess I was still testing this when you had already answered. I'm leaving my answer because it explains why the `\par` invoked by `enumerate` doesn't already cure things. By the way, I had to scroll 6 screens to the right to see the `\par` you added. A blank line would have been easier to see.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You just saved a guy from switching back to MS Word.

Comment: @Dan Your answer is a nice complement.  I have refilled the code lines so you no longer need to scroll to the right.  I used `\par` rather a blank line to indicate it really is a work around.

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a bug in `IEEEtran.cls` in the macro `\IEEEPARstart`. You can get around it by putting a blank line after `\end{enumerate}` and putting `\noindent` at the start of the following paragraph.

The problem comes down to the two parameters `\hangindent` and `\hangafter`. These are given values that allow the large `T` to fit into the two-line indentation in the first paragraph. These values must persist until the end of the paragraph, because only when the full paragraph is collected does TeX break it into lines using these values to get the lengths of the first two lines.

These values are reset to zero at the end of the paragraph, more specifically, at the first invocation of the TeX "*end-of-paragraph*" primitive. Unfortunately, in this example, that happens inside a group and the reset values are lost. Thus, the paragraph that follows has those same values and you get the same two lines of indentation as were used earlier to place that large `T`.

Another workaround is to put the following right after `\end{enumerate}`:

```
\makeatletter \@@par \makeatother
```

This invokes the primitive *end-of-paragraph* but not `\par` itself, so that the values of \hangindent and \hangafter are restored to 0, but the magic that keeps the next line from indenting remains in effect.